Here are two pieces of code about std::experimental::future, but I don't see the difference
[code 1]
template<typename Func>
std::experimental::future<decltype(std::declval<Func>()())>
spawn_async(Func&& func){
  std::experimental::promise<
    decltype(std::declval<Func>()())> p;
  auto res=p.get_future();
  std::thread t(
    [p=std::move(p),f=std::decay_t<Func>(func)]()
      mutable{
      try{
        p.set_value_at_thread_exit(f());
      } catch(...){
        p.set_exception_at_thread_exit(std::current_exception());
      }
  });
  t.detach();
  return res;
}

std::experimental::future<void> process_login( 
  std::string const& username, std::string const& password)
{
  return spawn_async([=](){
    return backend.authenticate_user(username, password);  
  }).then([](std::experimental::future<user_id> id){
    return backend.request_current_info(id.get());
  }).then([](std::experimental::future<user_data> info_to_display){
    try{
      update_display(info_to_display.get());
    } catch(std::exception& e){
      display_error(e);
    }
  });
}

[code 2]
std::experimental::future<void> process_login(
  std::string const& username, std::string const& password)
{
  return backend.async_authenticate_user(username, password).then(
    [](std::experimental::future<user_id> id){
      return backend.async_request_current_info(id.get());      
    }).then([](std::experimental::future<user_data> info_to_display){
      try{
        update_display(info_to_display.get());  
      } catch(std::exception& e){
        display_error(e);
      }
    });
}

This is the two-end code I saw in "C++ Concurrency in Action 2nd". The author simulated a process to explain std::experimental::future. When a user logs in to the application, he needs to send a message to the backend server to verify his identity; after completing the identity verification, he will request his account information from the backend server again, and finally update and display the requested information. The book mentioned that code 2 is better than code 1 because it implements true asynchrony, but I don't see why it is better. I hope friends who know can help me, I will be very grateful.
I searched on chatgpt, but its answer did not solve my problem.

Can it be that book is very old and predates C++11?

In what way async_authenticate_user differs than authenticate_user (launched by spawn_async)?

This book was published in 2021.
backend.authenticate_user(username,password) directly returns the user id, while async_authenticate_user returns a variable of type std::experimental::future<user_id>.

Are you sure it's not a new print of an old book? Because std::future has been in the language for 13 years now, no longer being experimental.

I noticed that this book was published in 2019, but it was translated into my native language in 2021. The title of the book is "C++ Concurrency in Action, Second Edition" and the author is Anthony Williams
